# How to make a knight randomly move in a chessboard?

Tags: java, random, chess

I have this program called **knight tour** where the knight moves around a chess board. I have been trying to figure out how to make the knight move randomly, instead of following a pattern.

I would like to know how to randomly move the knight.

Here's my code:

```
package assignment3;

import java.util.Random;

/*
 * knows its current position (row and column) 
 * knows the eight types of moves it can make
 * can tell you it’s current row and column
 * can determine whether a move of a given type is legal or not
 * can move
 */
public class Knight {
    private int boardSize = 8;
    private int[] rowMoves = {-1, -2, -2, -1, 1, 2, 2, 1};
    private int[] colMoves = {2, 1, -1, -2, -2, -1, 1, 2};

    public Knight() {
        //ignore this constructor
    }

    public void InitializeBoard() {
        //initialize board
        for (int i = 0; i < boardSize; i++)
            Arrays.fill(chessboard2[i], Integer.MIN_VALUE); //setting array to negative value
    }

    /**
     * calls method canMove to check if knight can move
     * moves knight
     */
    public boolean move(int moveNum, int x, int y, int[][] chessboard2) {
        Random rand = new Random(); 
        //if moveNum == 64 all squares have been visited 
        if (moveNum == 64) {
            System.out.println("\ntrue board is 64\n");
            return true;
        }
        
        //int nextRow = rand.nextInt(boardSize);
        //int nextCol = rand.nextInt(boardSize);
        
        //for loop to try 8 possibe moves
        for (int i = 0; i < rowMoves.length; i++) {
            int nextRow =  x + rowMoves[i];
            int nextCol =  y + colMoves[i];
       
            //check if postion is valid and not visited yet
            if (canMove(nextRow, nextCol) && chessboard2[nextRow][nextCol] == Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
                //if move is valid knight moves
                chessboard2[nextRow][nextCol] = moveNum + 1;
                
                //make next move
                if(move(moveNum + 1, nextRow, nextCol, chessboard2))
                   return true;

                //move(moveNum + 1, nextRow, nextCol);
           
                //if cant find next move: backtrack
                chessboard2[nextRow][nextCol] = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            }
        }
        
        return false;
    }     

    /**
     * calls method moveLegal from class Chessboard to see if move is legal
     * @return true if move is legal, else return false
     */
    public boolean canMove(int x, int y) {
        //if statement to check if currentRow and currentCol is whithin 
        //boundaries
        return(x >= 0 && x < boardSize && y >= 0 && y < boardSize);
    }

    public void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < boardSize; i++)
            System.out.println(String.join(" ", chessboard2[i]));
    }
 
    public void solve() {
        //setting array location [0][0] to 0
        chessboard2[0][0] = 1;
    
        //check move
        if (move(1, 0, 0)) // if true, it will print chess board
            print();
        else //if false, there is no solution
            System.out.print("no solution");
    }
}

public class TesterMain {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Knight test = new Knight();
        test.solve();
    }
}
```

Sorry if my code is a bit messy, I am still working on the program.

Comment: `chessboard2` is defined as a parameter of the `move` method but I also see a `chessboard2` in the `print` method. This is very ambiguous; where do you declare the second one? It must be a class member but I don't see it

Comment: Yes, chessboard2 it’s from another class. It shouldn’t be there. I forgot to comment it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a solution but it would require some refactoring:

- Create a `ChessMove` class that stores a row and a column move (integers)
- Add a `ChessMove[]` to store all possible moves that your knight can possibly do
- Refactor the `move` method:

  - Create an `ArrayList<ChessMove>` that stores all possible moves that your knight can do in its current position
  - Randomly select a move in this list using `rand.nextInt(possibleMoves.size());`

Here is the complete code:

```
package assignment3;

import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Knight {
    private int boardSize = 8;
    private int[][] chessboard2 = new int[boardSize][boardSize];

    private final ChessMove[] moves = {
                                          new ChessMove(-1, 2), 
                                          new ChessMove(-2, 1), 
                                          new ChessMove(-2, -1), 
                                          new ChessMove(-1, -2), 
                                          new ChessMove(1, -2), 
                                          new ChessMove(2, -1), 
                                          new ChessMove(2, 1), 
                                          new ChessMove(1, 2)
                                      };

    public Knight() {
        initializeBoard();
    }

    public void initializeBoard() {
        for (int i = 0; i < boardSize; i++)
            Arrays.fill(chessboard2[i], Integer.MIN_VALUE); //setting array to negative value
    }

    public boolean move(int moveNum, int x, int y) {
        //if moveNum == 64 all squares have been visited 
        if (moveNum == 64) {
            System.out.println("\ntrue board is 64\n");
            return true;
        }
        
        ArrayList<ChessMove> possibleMoves = new ArrayList<ChessMove>();
        for (ChessMove move : moves) {
            int nextRow =  x + move.row;
            int nextCol =  y + move.col;
       
            //check if postion is valid and not visited yet
            if (canMove(nextRow, nextCol) && chessboard2[nextRow][nextCol] == Integer.MIN_VALUE)
                possibleMoves.add(move);
        }
        
        if (!possibleMoves.isEmpty()) {
            Random rand = new Random();
            // Move choice is done here
            ChessMove chosenMove = possibleMoves.get(rand.nextInt(possibleMoves.size()));

            int nextRow =  x + chosenMove.row;
            int nextCol =  y + chosenMove.col;

            //if move is valid knight moves
            chessboard2[nextRow][nextCol] = moveNum + 1;
                
            //make next move
            move(moveNum + 1, nextRow, nextCol);
            return true;
        } else
            return false;
    }     

    public boolean canMove(int x, int y) {
        return (x >= 0 && x < boardSize && y >= 0 && y < boardSize);
    }

    public void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < boardSize; i++) {
            for (int cell : chessboard2[i])
                if (cell == Integer.MIN_VALUE)
                    System.out.print("*** ");
                else
                    System.out.print(String.format("%3d", cell) + " ");

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
 
    public void solve() {
        chessboard2[0][0] = 1;
    
        if (move(1, 0, 0)) // if true, it will print chess board
            print();
        else //if false, there is no solution
            System.out.print("no solution");
    }

    class ChessMove {
        int row = 0, col = 0;

        ChessMove(int r, int c) {
            this.row = r;
            this.col = c;
        }
    }
}

public class TesterMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Knight test = new Knight();
        test.solve();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I get:

Comment: ----------Knights Tour-----------

1 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 
-2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 
-2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 
-2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 
-2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 
-2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 -214748364

Comment: fixed it. But now Im getting no solution

Comment: I have written this code without testing it in Eclipse. I will try that this afternoon

Comment: @Straightup0 I've updated my answer, does it work for you?

Comment: This is what  I get:         ----------Knights Tour-----------

1 44 25 6 9 12 27 -2147483648 
24 -2147483648 2 13 26 5 8 11 
43 14 23 4 7 10 21 28 
-2147483648 3 -2147483648 41 22 -2147483648 32 -2147483648 
-2147483648 42 15 34 39 20 29 -2147483648 
16 35 40 -2147483648 18 33 38 31 
-2147483648 -2147483648 17 36 -214748

Comment: Seems to be working but something with the with Integer.MIN_VALUE seems wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: So from what I see, It's working. The knight moves at random, and the negative values that are being printed, are the locations the knight did not move to. Let's say I want to replace those negative numbers with this symbol * , I would have to fill the array with that symbol instead of negative values?

Comment: I updated the `print` method; do not forget to validate the solution if you think it answers your request

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to randomise your move is to create a list of valid moves for a given position of the knight and then select one at random. `List` and `Random` APIs go hand in hand:

```
//List<Integer> moves = ...
int move = moves.get(new Random().nextInt(moves.size()));
```

---

Restructuring your `move` method to something like this should do the job:

```
public boolean move(int moveNum, int x, int y, int [][] chessboard2) {
    // 1. List all valid moves
    List<Integer> validMoves = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    //for loop to try 8 possibe moves
    for(int i = 0; i < rowMoves.length; i++) {
        if (
            canMove(x + rowMoves[i], y + colMoves[i])
         && chessboard2[x + rowMoves[i]][y + colMoves[i]] == Integer.MIN_VALUE
        ) {
            validMoves.add(i);
        }
    }

    // 2. Try to make the move if any available
    if (validMoves.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }
    Random rand = new Random();
    int move = validMoves.get(rand.nextInt(validMoves.size()));
    int nextRow = x + rowMoves[move];
    int nextCol = y + colMoves[move]:
    chessboard2[nextRow][nextCol] = moveNumb + 1;
    return move(moveNum + 1, nextRow, nextCol, chessboard2);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain to me: List<Integer> validMoves = new ArrayList<Integer>();. I'm new with ArrayList. Please.

Comment: @Straightup0 It's a standard idiom that creates an empty list. Explaining how lists and generics work is out of scope of this question. Were you perhaps looking for a solution without lists?

Comment: No, any type of solution works, as long as I undertand it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an enum, let's call it Move, to represent every single move, and then make a list of these moves using Move.values().
Then you can shuffle the list with Collections.shuffle every time you want to move and take the first legal move.